# Zend Framework2 - difference between exchangeArray() and populate()

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to ask for the difference between exchangeArray() and populate() methods in ZF2 and how should I use each of them.
According to the ZF2 documentation:

> **Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable**
>
> Follows the definition of ArrayObject. Objects must implement either
>   the exchangeArray() or populate() methods to support hydration, and
>   the getArrayCopy() method to support extraction.

But it's unclear how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

So as the documentation points out, if we follow the definition of `exchangeArray()` from `ArrayObject` it simply replaces the the current data array with another. There is the potential to lose already stored data here if it isn't included again in the new array you're passing in.

```
public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    ...

    $storage = $this->storage;

    $this->storage = $data;

    return $storage;
}
```

To get around this you can implement a `populate()` function. A simple populating function could be:

```
public function populate($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $var) {
        $this->storage[$key] = $var;
    }
}
```

Here we're not at risk of losing data, only creating new entries or overwriting existing values.